# How to handle multiple JS libraries with different loading times in Angular?

Tags: angularjs

I am just learning Angular and I have some questions regarding the architecture of my app.

The project I will be working on will be using allot of external libraries: jQuery, jQuery.ui, jsPlumb and so on, with **different loading times**.

**I know that each code related to these libraries will have to be handled inside directives.**

I worked with Backbone which uses Require JS effectively - on each view, I could set what libraries I need and the view would be loaded as soon as those libraries are available.

Now, on angular side - what would be the correct way of handling this issue?

From the top of my head, I am thinking of:

1. Place checks inside the router - checking if the desired libraries for a certain route are loaded.
2. Place checks inside each directive - for example if one directive uses jsPlumb, place a check inside and return the directives content when that library is loaded - **I believe this could generate problems when interacting with other directives on the same view, which require multiple libraries with different loading times.**
3. Load angular only after every other library is loaded - that would lead to long loading times.

What's the best way to handle all those issues?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a factory to load the external library you need.  Return a deferred object for the library's script after it loads.  Here is one I used for d3 library:

```
var d3js = angular.module('d3', []);

d3js.factory('d3Service', ['$document', '$q', '$rootScope', '$window',
    function($document, $q, $rootScope, $window) {
        var d = $q.defer();

        function onScriptLoad() {
            // Load client in the browser
            $rootScope.$apply(function() { d.resolve($window.d3); });
        }
        // Create a script tag with d3 as the source
        // and call our onScriptLoad callback when it
        // has been loaded

        var scriptTag = $document[0].createElement('script');
        scriptTag.type = 'text/javascript';
        scriptTag.async = true;
        scriptTag.src = 'lib/d3.v3.js';

        scriptTag.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (this.readyState == 'complete') onScriptLoad();
        }

        scriptTag.onload = onScriptLoad;

        var s = $document[0].getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
        s.appendChild(scriptTag);

        return {
            d3: function() { return d.promise; }
        };

    }]);
```

then in your directive, use `then` function of the deferred to wait until it's ready

```
d3Service.d3().then(function(d3) {
    // place code using d3 library here
}
```

If your directive is needing access to multiple libraries, you can chain the deferreds.

```
d3Service.d3().then(function(d3) {
    someOtherLibSvc.getLib().then(function(lib){
        // place code using d3 library and someOtherLibrary here
    }
}
```

To avoid this chaining check out `bluebird` and use Promise.join, Angular comes with $q automatically so I just used that here.

Note: if you just load JQuery before angular, then [angular.element](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element) will already reference JQuery.  So you don't need to do this for JQuery, just load it in your main html page before Angular

Comment: Or you can read the article that this was pasted from - http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/d3-on-angular.html

Answer (score 1):

In short go 
  http://slides.com/thomasburleson/using-requirejs-with-angularjs#/

route.

However now suffer having to put the defines and requires everywhere. For a large application this may get messy if not planned carefully. Use grunt requirejs plugin for builds because without this things would be wash.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is the "correct" way to do this, but here is perhaps a simpler way to handle external libraries (in this case d3.js) within Angular 1.x code.

This is the same basic idea as @aarosil's answer (use a factory), but using fewer dependencies on other services - for what that's worth.

```
var app = angular.module('SomeApp', []);
app.factory('LibraryFactory', function () {
    var factory = {};

    factory.getD3 = function(callback) {
        if(!window.d3) {
            var script = document.createElement("script");
            script.src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.9/d3.min.js";
            document.head.appendChild(script);
            script.onload = function() {
                callback(window.d3);
            };
        } else {
            callback(window.d3);
        }
    };

    //factory.getSomeOtherLibrary = ...ditto

    return factory;
});
```

And to use the factory (eg, in a controller):

```
app.controller('SomeTrialWithD3Ctrl', function ($scope, LibraryFactory) {

    LibraryFactory.getD3(function main(d3) {
        // place code using d3 library here
    });
});
```

And of course, the callbacks can be chained if you need multiple libraries at once.